# Order an XML scoreboard and return it with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm creating a game where when a timer ends the user can enter their name. I pass the name and score to a PHP file with AJAX. That PHP file adds it to an XML file. I loop through it to create a table holding the scores and it's then returned to AJAX and I then output it on the screen with jQuery. I have all of this working fine right now.

What I want to accomplish is this:
1. After the score is added to the XML file I want to order the nodes according to score, in descending order
2. I then want to populate the table with the values in order. I'd also like to limit it to only the top 10 scores.

Basically where I'm running into problems coming up with a solution is the ordering. Once the XML is ordered populating the table and limiting it to 10 should be pretty straight forward. Any suggestions on how I should do this?

XML : http://people.rit.edu/lxl1500/Prog4/Project%202/scoreboard.xml

jQuery Ajax call:

```
function addScore(score,name){
    var url = 'scoreboard.php';
    $.post(url,{Score:score, Name:name},function(data){
    $('#score').html(data).show();
   });
}
```

scoreboard.php:

```
<?php
$score = $_POST['Score'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];

if($name == ''){
    $name = 'Player'.rand(0,5000);
}

$scoreboard = new domDocument;
$scoreboard->load('scoreboard.xml');

$root=$scoreboard->documentElement;

$entry = $scoreboard->createElement('entry');

$userScore = $scoreboard->createElement('score',$score);

$userName = $scoreboard->createElement('name',$name);

$entry->appendChild($userName);
$entry->appendChild($userScore);

$root->appendChild($entry);

$scoreboard->save('scoreboard.xml');

$scores = $scoreboard->getElementsByTagName('entry');

$string = '<table id="score-table" cellspacing="10"><tbody><tr><th align="left">User</th><th align="left">Score</th></tr>';


foreach($scores as $score){
    $getScore = $score->getElementsByTagName('score')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $getPlayer = $score->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $string.="<tr><td>$getPlayer</td><td>$getScore</td></tr>";
}

$string.='</tbody></table>';

echo $string;

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to do so is to create your XML element at the correct place instead of at the end, so that the XML file is always sorted. That being said, if you really want to manipulate data, using a database instead of XML should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about using a database but unfortunately it's a school server I've been creating this on and this server doesn't allow databases (they had a problem with people hacking it in the past). How would I create the XML in the correct place when I add it?

Comment: You'd have to traverse all the entries, find the first score which is lower than the one you want to insert, and insert your element before the one found via `insertBefore` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try now. I think I understand what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a sorted XML file, that is add the nodes to the xml file in sorted order, something like

```
$entries = $root->getElementsByTagName('entry');

$added = false;
foreach ($entries as $item) {
    if ($score <= $item->getElementsByTagName('score')->item(0)->nodeValue) continue;
    $root->insertBefore($entry, $item);
    $added = true;
    break;
}

// if not yet added, add it
if (!$added) {
    $root->appendChild($entry);
}
```

For this to work the file has to be sorted (or empty).

Comment: How would that would with an XML structure like this? I know that I need this to be empty before I do this...but if I wanted the structure to end up like this:



`<scoreboard>
<entry>
  <name>Lance</name>
  <score>14</score>
</entry>

<entry>
  <name>Player4023</name>
  <score>6</score>
</entry>

<entry>
  <name>Player4626</name>
  <score>10</score>
</entry>

<entry>
  <name>Player4267</name>
  <score>5</score></entry>
</scoreboard>`

Comment: @LanceLaughlin I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to keep the file unsorted, you'll have to sort it every time you want to display the top x values.

Comment: Basically what I'm asking: The way you have it the score value would be stored in the entry element but my score is a child of my entry element(along with the name). How do I test against that value? Or would it be better to just have a main entry tag and then have attributes for name and score?

Comment: @LanceLaughlin I changed it to check against the score node, The code above was to substitute the line `$root->appendChild($entry);`

Comment: Thank you. It's sort of working now. It adding the first entry...not getting any entries added after that. I'm probably just doing something wrong though. I'll keep working at it. Thanks for your help! I should be moved in the right direction now.

Comment: @LanceLaughlin I had a typo try now